# How do I get the child to inside a parent child on Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to put my data nested by user has a project has a task. I can't seem to get it inside the key.

Basically I wanted it to be like -

[image]

But my outcome is coming up as -

[image]

My JavaScript

```
<script>

    var database = firebase.database();

    var userRef = database.ref('/user');
    var projectRef = database.ref('/user/project');
    var taskRef = database.ref('/user/project/task');

    var userDisplay = userRef.push({
        username: 'userA',
        firstname: 'John',
        lastname: 'Smith'
        });

    var projectDisplay = projectRef.push({
        projectname: 'Project Test 1',
        projectdate: '12th December 2019'
        });

    var taskDisplay = taskRef.push({
        taskname: 'Task 1',
        taskdate: '12th December 2019',
        taskdetail: 'Task Testing'
    });

    console.log("Running...");

    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= userDisplay + ' ' + projectDisplay + ' ' + taskDisplay;  

</script>
```

Comment: are you ok with how the data first name, last name, username, project date, project name, task name, task detail, task name is currently saved into your DB ??

Comment: Yes they are saving to my db

Comment: Do you know how to get them into the id?

Comment: I actually have a doubt the First image structure and the way your data is storing currently with your code in the Second image is exactly what you are looking for. How else would you want to change it?? [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dvl4.png)

Comment: I was trying something like that the task test 1 belongs to project test 1 so that if another project was called project test 2 is created that task test 1 won't appear inside project test 2 if you get what I mean?

Comment: Yeah understood a project can have multiple tasks .. and a user can have multiple projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) method, as follows:

```
  var newUserKey = firebase
    .database()
    .ref()
    .child('user')
    .push().key;

  var newProjectKey = firebase
    .database()
    .ref()
    .child('user/' + newUserKey)
    .push().key;

  var newTaskKey = firebase
    .database()
    .ref()
    .child('user/' + newUserKey + '/' + newProjectKey)
    .push().key;

  var updates = {};

  updates['/user/' + newUserKey] = {
    username: 'userA',
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Smith'
  };

  var project = {};
  project[newProjectKey] = {
    projectname: 'Project Test 1',
    projectdate: '12th December 2019'
  };
  updates['/user/' + newUserKey]['project'] = project;

  var task = {};
  task[newTaskKey] = {
    taskname: 'Task 1',
    taskdate: '12th December 2019',
    taskdetail: 'Task Testing'
  };

  updates['/user/' + newUserKey]['project'][newProjectKey]['task'] = task;

  firebase
    .database()
    .ref()
    .update(updates);
```

Comment: The error: Uncaught Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains a path /user/-L_tgdK8qq3ycpG7RsEL that is ancestor of another path /user/-L_tgdK8qq3ycpG7RsEL/-L_tgdK8qq3ycpG7RsEJ

Comment: He made a typo change the `newPostKey` to `newUserKey`

Comment: @Thomas You are right, my initial solution generates an error (which is not due to the typo found by Fire-In-D-Hole) but to the fact that the `update()` method doesn't accept a path that is an ancestor of another path. I have fully rework the proposed solution and tested it.

Comment: Thanks for your help @RenaudTarnec I am new to firebase so I am just developing an understanding about nesting data etc. like structured

Comment: @ThomasJH Happy that I could help. One key point to note here is the use of the square brackets notation, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors. Happy Firebase development!